# How do RSpec's let and let! replace the original parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

In the process of writing tests in Rspec, if you encounter repeated required parameters {...}, you can use `let` to write it. This avoids writing a bunch of parameter preparations in advance for each example.

However, I don't quite understand the paradigm of Better Specs. His original code is this:

```
describe '#type_id' do
  before { @resource = FactoryBot.create :device }
  before { @type     = Type.find @resource.type_id }

  it 'sets the type_id field' do
    expect(@resource.type_id).to eq(@type.id)
  end
end
```

After using let it becomes the following

```
describe '#type_id' do
  let(:resource) { FactoryBot.create :device }
  let(:type)     { Type.find resource.type_id }

  it 'sets the type_id field' do
    expect(resource.type_id).to eq(type.id)
  end
end
```

It looks like the way to call a `resource` is pretty much the same, what's the benefit of using let ? What is the function of `FactoryBot.create:device`? And I can't see where `type` is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that lets are lazily evaluated and then memoized for the rest of the spec.

So in the first example, first the before blocks run and set the values of @resource and @type, and then the spec runs.

In the second example, the spec runs and when it references 'resource' the let block runs and returns a value, then when 'type' is referenced is runs the let block for that. The let block for type itself references 'resource' so it gets the value for resource that was memoized from the first time resource was referenced.

For what its worth, I disagree that lets are 'better'. My team and I have found that all they do is make specs much harder to understand for very little benefit, and we have removed all use of them in all our projects.

In fact, I consider that most of 'better specs' is actually poor advice, so if you are struggling to understand why something is 'better', you are very much not alone :)

Comment: You're missing one the major points of `let` which is that they can be used in shared contexts, shared examples etc and that you don't have to do a bunch of finagling like you would with a before block to seperate out the givens you want for a specific example. Used correctly its a very powerful tool.

Comment: I'm not missing anything, but thanks for your presumption